# @Schedule time wrong time

Tags: java

I have this @Schedule expression:

```
@Singleton
public class ArquivosSubmitidosScheduler {

    @EJB
    private DaoFactory daoFactory;

    @Schedule(persistent = false, minute = "45")
    public void fileSubmit() throws EmailException {
        System.out.println("Start");
     
    }
```

In my understand this scheduled is to be activated at 00:45 a.m since the default value for hour is 0,
but is being activated at 23:45. p.m

What is wrong?

Comment: In what timezone?

Comment: The timezone in jboss could affect the time scheduled? How can i check the timezone in jboss?

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html#timezone()):

> If a timezone is not specified, the schedule is evaluated in the context of the default timezone associated with the contianer<sup>[sic]</sup> in which the application is executing.

Comment: How can i check what is the timezone that is associated with my jboss 7?

Comment: @RômuloSorato `TimeZone.getDefault()`